# Issues Matching Sheet Name Containing the Nth Largest Value in Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having trouble matching the name of the sheet containing my nth largest value to the value returned.

My formula, which works, to get my top 5 largest numbers from my index, from cell D25, is:

> =LARGE('SHEET1:SHEET85'!D25, 1)

When I try the following formula, Excel doesn't recognize the first array in the formula, SHEET1:SHEET85 . Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is much appreciated.

> =INDEX('SHEET1:SHEET85',MATCH(LARGE('SHEET1:SHEET85'!D25, 1)))

Comment: You need to specify the column to index. Just the sheet names won't do.

Comment: When I specify column D25, it states I have too few arguments for my function starting at the *MATCH* function.

>=INDEX('SHEET1:SHEET85'!D25,MATCH(LARGE('SHEET1:SHEET85'!D25, 1)))

Comment: I hate to say it, but I do not believe that what you want to accomplish (finding the name of a sheet that a value occurs in via 3d reference) is possible. 

Microsoft support has a list of functions that can take a 3d reference [here] (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-c906f8b4-c648-4aa0-8063-65d38d03370f) none of these functions are lookup or reference.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Is there any way for me put the name of the sheet in a cell in the sheet itself and use that as a reference?